# Exporting a PNG in Blender 2.79

Tags: rendering, export, file-format, saving

I'm trying to export a render as just a PNG in Blender 2.79 (thats the latest one my Mac is capable of running).

I have `PNG` specified in the dropdown (see my settings below). I click `Render` and it takes me to the render screen, but from there I can only save it as a new Blender file.

I also watched a YouTube video which said to press the `Animation` button, but this gives me hundreds of PNGs, as though it is exporting an entire sequence.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After rendered, open an Image editor window, select the rendered image and choose from the file menu "Save as Image".

Comment: Thanks but what is the Image editor window? I've updated my question now with an extra screengrab of what I see

Comment: @user19860331  In 2.79 it is called UV/Image Editor: https://zupimages.net/up/22/46/0yq9.jpg

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! is there a way I can change the size of the image? as it seems to ignore the dimensions in my render settings

Comment: it should not ignore it, what you see in the UV/Image Editor may not be the full size, scroll to zoom. Also, in the Render panel that you show, the Resolution is 1920x1080 but 50%, so your image will be half this size, if you want it full size, choose 100% instead

Comment: @moonboots thank you!